# NoClassDefFoundError for org/spark_project/guava/cache/CacheLoader

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am trying to run a Spark program in Scala IDE for Eclipse using Maven. However, I get the `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` error on the line where I am initializing SparkConf. I also tried to add a dependency for Guava 14.0.1 but didn't solved my problem as well. :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/spark_project/guava/cache/CacheLoader
    at org.apache.spark.SparkConf.loadFromSystemProperties(SparkConf.scala:73)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkConf.<init>(SparkConf.scala:68)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkConf.<init>(SparkConf.scala:55)
    at oursparkapp2.SimpleApp$.main(SimpleApp.scala:8)
    at oursparkapp2.SimpleApp.main(SimpleApp.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:   org.spark_project.guava.cache.CacheLoader
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 5 more
```

The scala program (SimpleApp.scala) that I am trying to run is as follows:

```
package oursparkapp2

import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext

object SimpleApp {
  def main(args:Array[String]) {
    val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Hlelo")
  }
}
```

My pom.xml file is as follows:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>ez.spark</groupId>
  <artifactId>oursparkapp2</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-common</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Furthermore, Spark is running fine on my Terminal using the spark-shell command.

Comment: try to remove `<scope>provided</scope>` at spark dependency definition

Comment: No success, same error.

Answer (score 3):

I solved this problem by adding the dependency:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-network-common_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks, this works good for Spark 2.41, had to use jar spark-network-common_2.11-2.4.1.jar

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I solved it by upgrading Spark from version 2.0.0 to 2.2.0.

Answer (score 0):

For me the fix was to call the process with `spark-submit name_of_spark_file.py`
I believe it would also work with scala files.